# Calculating number of years between two dates, but rounded in the standard way

Tags: python

I want to get the rounded number of years between two dates. `relativedelta`'s `years` attribute almost does this, but because it serves a different use case it always rounds down instead of using standard rounding rules:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

almost_one_year_ago = date.today() - relativedelta(years=1) + relativedelta(days=1)
print(relativedelta(date.today(), almost_one_year_ago).years)
```

This outputs `0`, I want `1`.

Is there a good way to get the number of years as an integer following standard rounding rules? As in: round down if below .5 years, round up if at or above .5?

Comment: why to almost_one_year_ago are u taking the actual year, subtract 1 year and add 1 day? this will be not more one year. almost_one_year_ago = date.today() - relativedelta(years=1) and the result will be 1

Comment: I think, `almost_one_year_ago` is supposed to be a time interval that is **almost** one year, so this should be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that is compatible with leap years. It's still not as clean as I'd like, but it does the job:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def how_many_years_ago(input_date):
    difference = relativedelta(date.today(), input_date)
    result = difference.years

    # Round up if closer to the next year than the previous
    if difference.months >= 6:
        result += 1

    return result

# Exactly 1 year ago, should output 1
print(how_many_years_ago(date.today() - relativedelta(years=1)))

# Almost 1 year ago, should round up to 1
print(how_many_years_ago(date.today() - relativedelta(years=1) + relativedelta(days=1)))

# Too far removed from 35 years, should round down to 34
print(how_many_years_ago(date.today() - relativedelta(years=35) + relativedelta(months=8)))

# Almost 38 years ago, should round up to 38
print(how_many_years_ago(date.today() - relativedelta(years=38) + relativedelta(months=4)))
```

If I'm not overlooking certain caveats (like leap years), this implementation solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the difference in days, divide it by 365 and then round it like:

```
print(round((date.today() - almost_one_year_ago).days/365))
```

Another approach that takes into account leap years:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

target_date = date.today() - relativedelta(years=1) + relativedelta(days=1)

year_cnt = 0
one_year_ago = date.today() - relativedelta(years=1)
while ( target_date < one_year_ago ):
    year_cnt += 1 # because it's a full year
    one_year_ago -= relativedelta(years=1)

half_year_ago = one_year_ago + relativedelta(months=6)
if ( target_date <= half_year_ago ):
    year_cnt += 1 # because it's greater or equal a half year (>= 0.5)

print(year_cnt)
```

I just count all the full years and then check if the remaining time is more than half a year.

Comment: `days` works slightly differently. `relativedelta(date.today(), date.today() - relativedelta(days=364)).days` returns `30`, for example.

Comment: That's why I do not use relativedelta but `(date.today() - almost_one_year_ago).days`, which gives you 364.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My bad! How would you take into account the caveat that not all years have 365 days?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the years attribute you can use the days attribute, and calculate the amount of years. That way you can control how it is rounded

Comment: `days` works slightly differently. `relativedelta(date.today(), date.today() - relativedelta(days=364)).days` returns `30`, for example.

Comment: As above, I would just subtract the dates. As for leap year (i cannot comment the above because of low reputation). It depends on how you want to interpret leap years. We have leap year every four years, so your calculation will be wrong when calculating deltas of more than 365*4 years.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that, unfortunately! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm I'm a bit hesitant to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I found a solution that probably solves my problem, and doesn't require manual handling of leap years. I posted it below. If you don't see any hidden caveats there, then incrementing based on `months >= 6` will do the trick for me!